# console.log() input value?

Tags: html, forms, input, key-value

Why won't this code just take the input value and console.log() it?

The updated code reads.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="get">
    <h1>thank you</h1>
    <a href="index.html">
      <button>Home</button>
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="https://github.com/shanegibney/link-two-pages">
      <button>Back to repositoryy</button>
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
<form>
    <input type="number" id="Idkey" value="5" min="0" max="10">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
  </body>{
  <script>
   let Idkey = document.getElementById(Idkey).value;
console.log(Idkey);
  </script>
</html>
```

The submit button is not rendering at all.

The error I get is,

```
settings.html:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

Comment: Your HTML has errors in it. [Use a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Comment: Your JavaScript has syntax errors in it. They should be reported in the console so you should see them in the place you are expecting the log that they are preventing.

Comment: you have a comma in one of your console.log statements. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The script will only read the initial value in the input field (it will always log `5`).

You need to tell the script to read the input value each time the submit button is clicked by adding the `oninput` attribute, like this:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" value="5" id="Idkey" oninput="myfunction()" />
</form>
<script>
  function myfunction() {
    let val = document.getElementById("Idkey").value;
    console.log(val);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. I've updated the original question. But unfortunately it still isn't working.

Comment: There are still some errors, the initial DOCTYPE has no starting <, there is a { after the </body> tag and most importantly in the script you try to read the value by saying getElementById(Idkey) but it should be getElementById("Idkey"), adding the quotes.

Comment: I have added a possible solution to your problem